# How can I break out of the if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, break

My code's goal is to print out the title of the book if the title contains the given argument. 
The tests are provided, and passes all of the tests except this given input: 
The expected output is "Harry", however the actual output I am getting is "No hits found for search term: Harry". So the first if statement is not breaking for Harry. How can I fix this problem, been looking where I'm doing wrong but couldn't find it. 
Here is my code:

```
 public void execute(LibraryData data) {
        for (BookEntry book : data.getBookData()) {
            if (book.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(givenArgument.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.println(book.getTitle());
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("No hits found for search term: " + givenArgument);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your if statement is probably wrong and that is why it doesn’t get to the break of that if, it never gets inside it.

Comment: You only look at the first book.

Comment: The ‘break‘ statement breaks out of a loop (for, while), but __does not work inside ‘if‘__, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28816407

Answer (score 3):

Your code is only checking the **first book**, since you `break` out of the loop in either case. The code to print "No hits" must be moved outside the loop, because you don't know if there was a hit until after a full iteration of the list.

To then know if a book was found, you need a `boolean` variable to remember that.

```
boolean found = false;
for (BookEntry book : data.getBookData()) {
    if (book.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(givenArgument.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println(book.getTitle());
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (! found) {
    System.out.println("No hits found for search term: " + givenArgument);
}
```

You can also change the loop to only do the searching, and print after the loop. That is actually a good strategy, called [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (SoC).

```
// Search for book
BookEntry foundBook = null;
for (BookEntry book : data.getBookData()) {
    if (book.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(givenArgument.toLowerCase())) {
        foundBook = book;
        break;
    }
}

// Print search result
if (foundBook == null) {
    System.out.println("No hits found for search term: " + givenArgument);
} else {
    System.out.println(foundBook.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: To extend your SOC a separate method `List<Book> findBooksContaining(String titlePart)` would allow more than one occurrences of e.g. "Harry".

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that you are not checking **all** the books before printing the error message.

Try this:

- Enclose your for loop in a block with a label.
- if the the book is found, print the title, break out of that block and don't
  print the error message.
- Otherwise, the error message will be printed and will fall thru to the end of the method.

Another way is to simply return when you found the book.

Either way ensures that you:

- Print the title when the book is found and exit the method.
- Print the error method after checking all books.

```
    public void execute(LibraryData data) {
      outer:
      {
        for (BookEntry book : data.getBookData()) {
            if (book.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(givenArgument.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.println(book.getTitle());
                break outer;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No hits found for search term: " + givenArgument);
      }
    }
```

You can also just return when you find the book.

```
    public void execute(LibraryData data) {
        for (BookEntry book : data.getBookData()) {
            if (book.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(givenArgument.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.println(book.getTitle());
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No hits found for search term: " + givenArgument);
     }
```

Comment: There must be severe constraints to favour a design with `break` and _labeled block_ (here `outer`) instead of applying short-circuited `return` after found (in order to _exit the method_!) 

Comment: Just showing ways to avoid using a boolean.  Neither method was really favored.  The second  method is clearly the best.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to break the loop, in the `else` block

Answer (score -2):

#### Reconsider purpose of your if-statement

Your if condition decides whether title matches or not.
If not matching at first book you most likely want to continue to probe following books.
So **don't put `break` inside your if-statement** but instead count or collect matching books inside if.

*Remember:*
Only one conditional branch of your if-construction is executed, either *if consequential block* or *else consequential block*.

#### To discontinue on first match

Put the `break;` after your if-statement to break the loop 
only if one (or more, according your requirements) match was found.
This would stop further iteration.

By clever redesign you could even use `return` for that:

```java
public boolean containsInTitle(LibraryData data, String givenArgument) {
   for (BookEntry book : data.getBookData()) {
      if (book.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(givenArgument.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println("Found matching book:" +book.getTitle());
        return true; // replacement for break to exit on first match
       } else {
         System.out.println("Book does not contain term '" + givenArgument + "': " + book.getTitle());
       }
   }
  // if no book matches: default exit is
  return false;
}
```